# How to navigate to a Lightning Application from a standard record whilst maintaining header and sidebar

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

I have developed a custom lightning application consisting of native lightning components to allow the user to execute a complex process that manipulates the data from the record it originates from (I am passing the record Id to the lightning application).

How can I navigate from the standard record (with the lightning experience turned on) to the custom lightning app whilst:

1. Populating the source record id into an attribute on the lightning application (either via URL parameter or other)
2. Maintain the header and sidebar

Comment: Hey David, stuck at the same issue. Was able to open custom lightning app in new tab without standard sidebar & header. Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to stay on the record page, just collapse the record details and expose your component? Perhaps you could switch record types, which would allow you to use two different layouts, one with your component, one without?

Answer (score 0):

You can embedd that lightning application into a VisualForce page and redirect to that VisualForce Page as per the sidebarsa and header requirements.